# Can I use NULL in a IN close?

Tags: t-sql

How do I add the empty string and null to the list of values in the parenthesis. I think for the empty is just adding '' but for the null, I'm not that sure.

```
UPDATE ProjectsActiveNotes
SET    NoteTypeID = 1
      ,NoteType = 'USER - CLIENT'
WHERE  NoteCategory = 'Client' AND
       NoteSubCategory IN
       (
        ''
        ,'Delivery'
        ,'Estimate'
        ,'Invoicing'
        ,'Placement'       
       )
GO
```

Thank for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use `ISNULL` :

```
UPDATE ProjectsActiveNotes
SET    NoteTypeID = 1
      ,NoteType = 'USER - CLIENT'
WHERE  NoteCategory = 'Client' AND
       ISNULL(NoteSubCategory,'') IN
       (
        ''
        ,'Delivery'
        ,'Estimate'
        ,'Invoicing'
        ,'Placement'       
       )
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use NULL in [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) but you can add it to the WHERE clause;

```
UPDATE ProjectsActiveNotes
SET    NoteTypeID = 1
      ,NoteType = 'USER - CLIENT'
WHERE  NoteCategory = 'Client' AND
       (NoteSubCategory IN
       (
        ''
        ,'Delivery'
        ,'Estimate'
        ,'Invoicing'
        ,'Placement'       
       ) or NoteSubCategory is null)
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
UPDATE  ProjectsActiveNotes
SET     NoteTypeID = 1 ,
        NoteType = 'USER - CLIENT'
WHERE   NoteCategory = 'Client'
        AND COALESCE(NoteSubCategory, '') IN ( '', 'Delivery', 'Estimate',
                                               'Invoicing', 'Placement' )
```